# Box with dotted lines and zero when using ctrl+left mouse click in a webpage

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, webpage

I'm wondering which is the meaning of the number zero which appears when I use ctrl+left mouse click in a webpage. I didn't find an explanation online.

[image]

Comment: What browser does the box appear on?

Comment: Hello @ReddyLutonadio in Google Chrome